# ToolbarItemが表示されない

Tags: swift

ビルドして、ListのNavigationLinkで遷移するとその遷移先のViewのToolbarItemが表示されません。
みなさんそうですか？

Comment: roa さん、質問に回答するためには、質問者さんの問題を回答者が再現できることが必要です。roa さんのお手元では明確な問題が起こっていても、それと類似の問題を回答者が再現するためには roa さんのお手元で何が起こっているかの具体的で詳しい説明が必要なのです。こちらのご質問の場合だとたとえば、具体的にどんなコードなのかコピペするだとか、どう表示されるのかスクリーンショットで説明するだとかして、roa さんの状況を正確に教えてほしいです。ヘルプページにある[「再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)も参考にしてみてください。質問は後からでも [edit] でき、改善していくことができます。

Answer (score 1):

ToolbarItemは各画面ごとに設定する必要があります。

以下のようなExtensionで簡単に各画面に一行で実装可能ですが、Buttonのaction内容がその画面に依存している場合、各画面で実装が必要です。

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      NavigationLink("View1") {
        NavigationLink("View2") {
          Text("View3")
        }
          .customToolbar("View2")
      }
      .customToolbar("View1")
    }
  }
}

extension View {
  func customToolbar(_ title: String) -> some View {
    self.toolbar {
      ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        Button(title) {
          
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```